# How to programmatically update an Eclipse feature and ints plugins

Tags: eclipse, provisioning, osgi-bundle

How can I programmatically update an Eclipse feature by pointing to a p2 repository?

I can install features using org.eclipse.tycho.p2.facade.internal.P2ApplicationLauncher class by setting the application name as org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director. However, this fails when I install a newer version of a feature which already exist in eclipse environment.

Installing sample.student.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1.
Installation failed.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: sample.student.mgt.feature 4.2.1 (sample.student.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1)
 Software currently installed: sample.student.mgt.feature 4.2.0 (sample.student.mgt.feature.group 4.2.0)
 Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
  sample.student.mgt.feature 4.2.1 (sample.student.mgt.feature.jar 4.2.1)
  sample.student.mgt.feature 4.2.0 (sample.student.mgt.feature.jar 4.2.0)
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: sample.student.mgt.feature 4.2.0 (sample.student.mgt.feature.group 4.2.0)
  To: sample.student.mgt.feature.jar [4.2.0]
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: sample.student.mgt.feature 4.2.1 (sample.student.mgt.feature.group 4.2.1)

Any solution for this is appreciated.

Comment: Using **internal** classes is breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)